# Selecting row from among most recently-inserted rows in MySQL/MariaDB table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm going to be logging sensor data to a MariaDB table... basically, three columns:

- ts -- TIMESTAMP of reading
- srcID -- TINYINT UNSIGNED representing id of sensor reporting the data
- value -- SMALLINT UNSIGNED -- a 16-bit value

There are three primary use cases:

1. Data inserted into the table as sensor readings are taken... approximately 4/minute/sensor. Generally speaking, records will be inserted immediately after reading the sensor... and not inserted at all if something causes insertions to fail for more than a few minutes.
2. Fetching the newest sensor reading for each source, going back a maximum of 15 minutes. This will happen approximately once every 15 seconds & needs to be very fast.
3. Selecting values from the past hour/day/week/month/etc for longer-term graphs. This will be a relatively infrequent occurrence, and can be tolerably slow.

My big questions...

1. Is there a MySQL/MariaDB table type that physically stores rows in chronological order of insertion time? (ARCHIVE, perhaps?)
2. Is there a way to tell the query optimizer, "execute {this-query}, but instead of doing a full table (or partition) scan from the beginning, just scan the 500 newest rows in the table"? (theory: if rows are stored in the order they're inserted, the latest reading might not literally be the last-inserted... but it's almost certainly going to be AMONG the last few hundred rows inserted).

I could *swear* I remember reading about a storage engine like this for MySQL or MariaDB that's optimized for "logging-type" records and works approximately like this... but now that I'm actually looking, I can't find anything.

I know I could partition the table by range on "ts" (and in fact, WILL be partitioning by range on "ts"), but it would be nice if I could get away with just one partition per week or month, instead of having to manage one partition per DAY (it's one thing for a query that gets executed once in a blue moon to be slow... it's another matter entirely for a query that gets executed every few hundred milliseconds to be slow).

Answer (score 1):

How many sensors?  For the sake of "doing the math", I'll assume 100.  If there are a million sensors, then there are serious scaling problems.  (Anyway, 257 would blow out the `TINYINT`.)

4/min/sensor * 100 sensors = 7 rows inserted/second -- nowhere near trouble on the `INSERT` side.

Use InnoDB.  Let's estimate 40 bytes/row, including as-yet-unspecified index(es).  That adds up to about 8GB/year.  No problem, I assume.

How long will you keep the data?  This won't matter since I will design the rest to scale adequately.

It sounds like you want to read all sensors for the last 15 minutes?  That will be 6K rows (for 100 sensors)?  240KB.  All we need to worry about is not scattering the rows so much that they can't stay cached for 15 minutes.  *No* problem.

There are only(?) two choices for the `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
(ts, srcID)
(srcID, ts)
```

Because of clustering, the `value` will be right there.  (Read about the "clustering" of the PK with the data in InnoDB.)

I tell people "you can't design the schema until you specify the queries".  So here goes...

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE ts >= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE;
```

That *begs* for `PRIMARY KEY(ts, ...)` so that the query scans through 240KB of Data -- very fast, very efficient, no waste.  The `SELECT` will take only a fraction of a second.  So, the CPU will be snoring most of the time.

For the older graphs, the queries can be "fast enough".  The "last hour" will be only for times as slow as the 15-minute query.  For others, I will recommend using a Summary table to make the day query almost as fast as the hour query, thereby letting the CPU get even more beauty sleep.

The Summary table would have

```
hr -- timestamp truncated to the hour
srcID
avg_value -- the AVG() over the hour
min_value -- if you want it
max_value -- if you want it
num_readings -- COUNT(*) if you want it
PRIMARY KEY(hr, srcID)
```

Just after the top of each hour, you would add a new set of rows.  The daily/weekly/etc graphs would fetch from the summary table instead of the main ("Fact") table.  This is much smaller, hence much faster.

Optionally, you could toss the data from the main table after summarizing it!  This shrink your disk footprint from 8GB/year to much less than 1GB/year.

More on Summary Tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Your 'big' questions:

Q1:  There is no datatype or engine; the `PRIMARY KEY` of InnoDB controls the order.

If you choose to remove data after some period of time, `PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(ts))` would lead to a very fast `DROP PARTITION`.  [*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) .  Aim for no more than 50 partitions -- there are inefficiencies if you have "too many" partitions.  If you keep the data for 5 years, then monthly partitions are probably advised.

Q2:  Again the PK of InnoDB, together with the "buffer_pool" being a "cache", says that the "latest" rows will be sitting in RAM waiting for fetching.  (There are exceptions, such as after a reboot or perhaps some significant maintenance.)  Even if the cache is "cold", the "clustering" says that the minimum number of fetches from disk will be performed.  240K=15*16KB blocks -- perhaps 150ms on a spinning drive; even faster on SSD.  And the Summary table shrinks that by another factor of 10 (or whatever).

You may have read an *old* article about MyISAM being optimal for logging.  That's an old wive's tale.  InnoDB has improved; MyISAM is stagnated, and is being deprecated.  Furthermore, the clustering of the PK in InnoDB may make your main `SELECTs` run *faster* than with MyISAM, which handles indexes differently.